# How would I set up my if formula to only read first 2 decimal point?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 columns that I was to use the if function on. I want to have it where if this two cell have the same number then it would say "Good" and if it doesn't then "Error".

The formula I am using is `if(A1=B1, "Good", "Bad")`

B1 is the sum of C1:F1

The problem is that D1 have a formula that calculate the percent of A1 like `"=5%*A1"`

So sometime A1 and B1 is not exactly the same, and it would read it as "Error" even though it could be off by .001

How can I fix this problem? I want to have it where if B1 is round up it would be ok.

Comment: `=round(value,2)` would take the number, rounded to the 2nd decimal place; you could also use `=text(value,"#.#0")`, but that may not work for later use (comparing number to string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the formula ROUND() for that:

```
+IF(ROUND(A1,2)=ROUND(B1,2),"Good","Bad")
```